# How to set Mitel 5224 ringer volume in configuration?

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip, mitel

We have several Mitel 5224 SIP phones, but can't seem to find out to make the ringer volume setting persist after it reboots. Can the ringer volume can be set somewhere in the XML configuration file?